# Arduino: "error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token"

Tags: c, arduino-uno

When I try to compile this code, I get the error message in the title. Im new to this and not sure if something is just going completely over my head. This code is just to test the wiring on an RC car that im trying to turn autonomous with arduino. I've seen this error message before as a question here, but i cant find a way to apply the solution there to my code. I've tried looking at all of the brackets and making sure that they pair with each other (ex. {}, not {{ or }} or }{). I want to be able to fix this by thanksgiving break so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
int driveneg = 9;
int drivepos = 5;   /*this shows all my variables*/
int steeringneg = 6;
int steeringpos = 3;

byte speed =255;

    void setup ();
    {
        pinMode (steeringneg, OUTPUT); 
        pinMode (steeringpos, OUTPUT); /*setting the motors to output*/
        pinMode (driveneg, OUTPUT);
        pinMode (drivepos, OUTPUT);
    }
    void loop ();
    {
        forward();
        delay (2000);
        backward();
        delay (2000);
    }
    void backward();
    {
        analogWrite (9,0);
        analogWrite (5, speed);/*defines forward and backward functions*/
        analogWrite (6, 0);
        analogWrite (3, speed);
    }
    void forward();
    {
        analogWrite (9, speed);
        analogWrite (5, 0);
        analogWrite (6, speed);
        analogWrite (3, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the semi-colons (`;`) after the function parentheses, like so:

```
void setup ()
{
    ...
}
```